# Ubuntu Live DVD boot stuck at loading screen

Tags: boot, dvd, livedvd

So I burnt the newest Ubuntu.iso on a DVD using the Windows 10 standard DVD burning feature. Now I am booting from this DVD, but the boot is stuck on the loading screen (this one: http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-tD-yi63zyj8/UAEATpqyfSI/AAAAAAAAWKA/12PoRg9MHwk/s320/How-to-Customize-Ubuntu-Splash-and-Login-Screen.jpg) for more than an hour now.

Is this possible, or do you think there is a problem?

Comment: It's strongly recommend to boot from USB in any new hardware.

Comment: Ok, and why is that so? I still think Live DVD Ubuntu should work fine on a DVD, shouldn't it? I don't want to install it... I just use the "try Ubuntu without installing" option.

Comment: One more reason to use USB, optical drives are extremely slow in comparison. But yes, DVD should also work. IF you're still seeing it try pressing ESC. Then you may or may not see a warning or error message. If so [edit] and post it.

Comment: Alright, I'll try that when I'm back home.